# Update External Data Field in SPD workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, updatelistitems, external-data

I created a Workflow in SharePoint Designer that create an item in a List B that was created in List A.
The issue that the creation is OK. but when i Update the item, the workflow not delete the old item. It add a new line with the new item.

when i log the error : "The field 'Domiciliation' of type 'BusinessData' cannot be used in the query filter expression."

how i can update an External Data Field with SPD workflow and delete the old line. I need only one domiciliation in list B

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update a field in an external data source with a SharePoint workflow.

You will need a middleware process/tool to update data outside of SharePoint.

Comment: I think the question title is misleading. I think they might mean an external list; as in not the list that the workflow is triggered on.

Comment: @unibod : I mean External Data Field (Business Data/ BCS) not external List :)

Comment: @teylyn : Please which kind of middleware? can you give me some examples?

Comment: @teylyn : okay I've removed my answer so it does not mislead.